# Cannot move email to another folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

The line below doesn't work with my Sub. It only shows Add, Application,Class, Count etc. but doesn't really prompt me with the Move function.

```
objItems.Move objDestFolder
```

Below are the rest of the code:

```
Sub MoveEmail()

Dim objNS As NameSpace
Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim objDestFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim obj As Object
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objItems As Outlook.items

    Set objOL = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = objOL.Application.Session

'specify the Inbox Folder you want to extract the email
Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("For Processing")
Set objItems = objFolder.items

Set objDestFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("For Temp")

For Each obj In objItems
    If obj.Class = olMail Then
        objItems.Move objDestFolder

        Set obj = Nothing
        Set objItems = Nothing
        Set objFolder = Nothing
        Set objOL = Nothing
        Set objDestFolder = Nothing

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling Move on the Items object, not MailItem. You also should not use "for each" if you are modifying the collection. Use a down loop.
Change your code to

```
For i = objItems.Count to 1 step -1
    set obj = objItems.Item(I)
    If obj.Class = olMail Then
        obj.Move objDestFolder
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Works like a charm Thank you!  I'm also using a code which extracts email to excel. Should I use the down loop as well?

    `For Each obj In objItems`

    `If obj.Class = olMail Then`
        `myXLApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = FormaT(obj.ReceivedTime, "mm/dd/yyyy")`
        `myXLApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = obj.SenderEmailAddress`
         `myXLApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) = obj.Subject`
         `myXLApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = ActiveAgnt`
              `i = i + 1`
    `End If`

Comment: If you only read the data, you can use "for each" or an up "for" loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you're using a `For Each` loop, but then setting the collection variable which you're iterating over to nothing, once the object you've iterated to is a Mail Item?

At any rate, I do not believe you can move a whole folder of items at once, hence IntelliSense not providing you with the option to use that Method with the object.

You would need to iterate over each Mail Item within the folder and move them individually.

```
For Each obj In objItems
    If obj.Class = olMail Then
        obj.Move objDestFolder    
    End If
Next obj
```

Comment: Next time I do this I am going to switch to 100% down loops.